# The status of your app has changed to Invalid Binary

Tags: ios

The status of my app has changed to Invalid Binary, so, what might be the issue?

Comment: Did your uploads work in the past and is this a new issue or are you trying to upload for the very first time?

Comment: I am trying to upload the app for the very first time

Comment: Did you verify for deprecated API usage?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project uses any deprecated API. `UIWebView` started causing this issue recently. So make sure to migrate to `WKWebView` in this case.

Usually you should have some more info about the issue in the email you receive when the binary finishes uploading and there were some issues with it.

This is an example text for deprecated API usage in the email you receive if there are issues with your binary:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).